# CodePush 400: {"status":400,"name":"Error","message":"Missing required query parameter \"deployment_key\""}

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-code-push

After rebuilding with `React Native 0.70.1/react-native-code-push 7.05 project/Xcode 14/Monterey` , `npx react-native run-ios` launch successfully without any error but the console screen throws error:

```
[CodePush] An unknown error occurred.
 LOG  [CodePush] 400: {"status":400,"name":"Error","message":"Missing required query parameter \"deployment_key\""}
```

Then I create a new app in MS appcenter for IOS and replaced the app secret with the new one just created in `AppCenter-Config.plist` in Xcode. But the error is the same. Before rebuilding the app, I verify that the latest react native code push 7.0.5 works with the release of React Native 0.70.

The app build in Xcode 14 went successfully. What is missing with the appcenter or app config?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error because I forgot to set the `CodePushDeploymentKey` in`Info.plist` :)

Now that I have a configuration-specific `CODEPUSH_KEY` in build settings, and have set the `CodePushDeploymentKey` to `$(CODEPUSH_KEY)` in `Info.plist`, it works!